# I want to know the information about Progress 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm so new to progress, just know basics.

I want to become developer in progress openedge but i don't have any sources to guide me.

Can anyone please help on this , if you any link or documents kindly suggest me.

I'm doing maintenance work in progress but want to move to development.
Development is there in Progress right ??

Comment: There are already a couple of questions here like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731749/how-to-start-with-progress-4-gl

Answer (score 0):

You can start to study OpenEdge ABL with Progress OpenEdge Developers Kit: Classroom Edition

[Progress OpenEdge Developers Kit: Classroom Edition](https://www.progress.com/openedge/classroom-edition)